# Android Local Notification with Angular Service Worker

Tags: angular, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I'm building a PWA using the latest version of Angular.

I'm making use of the [Angular Mobile Toolkit](https://github.com/angular/mobile-toolkit) and I want to send Local Notifications using [angular/service-worker](https://github.com/angular/mobile-toolkit/tree/master/service-worker/worker). But I can't make it work.

I'm able to subscribe and send notification from a server, but I would like to send a notification from my app itself. I tried using [angular2-notifications](https://github.com/flauc/angular2-notifications), it works well on a desktop, but the constructor

```
new Notification(title, options)
```

from the Notification API doesn't work anymore on Android, so it doesn't suit me.

Is there any way to use [angular/service-worker](https://github.com/angular/mobile-toolkit/tree/master/service-worker/worker) to send local notifications on Android (Chrome)? Or maybe another alternative.

**EDIT**

Maciej answer pointed me to the right direction, I was able to make it work using the following piece of code

```
navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration() 
         .then((reg) => { 
                reg.showNotification(title, noti); 
           });
```

P.S.: Be aware that I used this together with [angular/service-worker](https://github.com/angular/mobile-toolkit/tree/master/service-worker/worker). I used [angular/service-worker](https://github.com/angular/mobile-toolkit/tree/master/service-worker/worker) to register the service-worker and the code above uses the registered service-worker. Also, be aware that for the service-worker to work you need a secure connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome on Android is not compatible with the Notification API from HTML5, so you won't be able to send `local notifications`.

As far as I can see in the `@angular/service-worker` source code, for displaying notifications, they are using following method:

`this.worker.showNotification(desc['title'], options);`

`this.worker` is an object of type `VersionWorker`.

So probably there is some way to reuse `this.worker` for your use.

Full code of Push plugin written by Angular team, can be found here: https://github.com/angular/mobile-toolkit/blob/master/service-worker/worker/src/plugins/push/index.ts

Example repo for service-worker plugin can be found here: https://github.com/maciejtreder/ng-http-sw-proxy (catalog `plugin`).

Comment: Hello Maciej, thanks for your answer. I'm aware that Chrome on Android is not compatible with the Notification API. But I can use the Service Worker API (in my case I'm using through [angular/service-worker](https://github.com/angular/mobile-toolkit/tree/master/service-worker/worker)) to subscribe for notifications from a server. I'm wondering if I can use the same API to send local notifications

Comment: Updated again ;)

Comment: Thanks once again Maciej, is there any way that I can import the Push plugin inside my project? I tried using `import { PushImpl } from '@angular/service-worker/plugins/push'` but it throws me a bunch of errors. I also tried importing directly from the JS bundle with `import { PushImpl } from '@angular/service-worker/bundles/worker-basic'` it compiles but I get an error on runtime.

Comment: As a package-name says, these plugins are created for the service-worker purpose. Not for "standard" javascript.

Comment: I think I managed to make it work without using the angular/service-worker, using this following piece of code 
`navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration()
                    .then((reg) => {
                        reg.showNotification(title, noti);
                    });
`
But I wasn't able to test it because I can't register the service worker on Android yet because of SSL, but I'll comment here if it works. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction.

Comment: I was finally able to test and it worked perfectly, I'll accept your answer since it pointed me to the right direction, thanks once again :D

Comment: Glad to hear that.